# TypeError 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating $ event)

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load a local HTML file in my Android application's webview. The  HTML file references a local copy of `jquerymobile.js`. My problem
is when the application is launched, the following error is thrown:

`TypeError 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating $ event)`

This happens even without any code written that uses the `jquery lib`.This error does not happen when I load the jquery library from their `CDN`.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Added code for more clarity:

This is where the `WebView` loads the `url`

```
try {
        //this reads the jquerymobile as a string
        jmobile = readFileAsString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  wview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,           JsResult result) {
                    //Required functionality here
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
           }   
  });
 wview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(wview1, url);
              wview1.loadUrl("javascript:"+jmobile);
            // do your stuff here
        }
    });
    wview1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

The following works

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

**But if I change the script src to a local copy of jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js, I get the type error**

Answer (score 2):

When you reference local files, put those references in this order:

1. CSS of mobile
2. JS of jQuery core
3. JS of jQuery mobile.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue as follow:
You have a HTML file and JS file in local. Now you need Load HTML and JS.But failed.

Could you show me how do you load the HTML file and inject the jquerymobile.js into it.

I usually do it like this:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient ());

clsss myWebViewClient extend WebViewClient{
     @Override
     OnPageFinished(View view, String Url){
          view.loadUrl("javascript:"+String in jquerymobile.js);
     }
}

WebView.loadUrl("test.html");
```

Would this help you?

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined at null.